# state.svg.transition is not a function - Sunburst-chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, sunburst-diagram

While creating a sunburst using sunburst-chart.js I am getting the below error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: state.svg.transition is not a function
at Function.update (sunburst-chart.module.js:187)
at eval (kapsule.min.js:1)
at f (kapsule.min.js:1)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

---

below is the function at (sunburst-chart.module.js:187):

```
state.svg.transition(transition$$1).tween('scale', function () {
    var xd = interpolate(state.angleScale.domain(), [focusD.x0, focusD.x1]);
    var yd = interpolate(state.radiusScale.domain(), [focusD.y0, 1]);
    return function (t) {
      state.angleScale.domain(xd(t));
      state.radiusScale.domain(yd(t));
    }; 
});
```

Comment: state.svg should be initialised with an svg element: `state.svg = el.append('svg');`. What environment are you running this in? Does it have SVG support?

Comment: Thanks @rup [Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup). I am trying to run this on AWS Linux. I am fairly new to sunburst-chart.js, can you please clarify, where do I initialize state.svg?